# POST Data from full calendar to Google Calendar using Codeigniter

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I am building an application using `codeigniter` and i am stuck now on a place. I have integrated the `full calendar` into my application which is working perfectly. Now i need to make an event like if someone `insert an event on full calendar using my application` it will `automatically insert that event on google calendar also using google calendar API`. I have install google client api via composer but that doesn't help also. I have make an function by getting an idea from google calendar for developer but it also given me an error. Kindly check the issue and i am grateful for any help

This is a function on my controller:

```
 function google_event(){
        $event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
            'summary' => 'Google I/O 2015',
            'location' => '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
            'description' => 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer products.',
            'start' => array(
              'dateTime' => '2021-09-28T09:00:00-07:00',
              'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
            ),
            'end' => array(
              'dateTime' => '2021-09-28T17:00:00-07:00',
              'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
            ),
            'recurrence' => array(
              'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
            ),
            'attendees' => array(
              array('email' => 'lpage@example.com'),
              array('email' => 'sbrin@example.com'),
            ),
            'reminders' => array(
              'useDefault' => FALSE,
              'overrides' => array(
                array('method' => 'email', 'minutes' => 24 * 60),
                array('method' => 'popup', 'minutes' => 10),
              ),
            ),
          ));
          
          $calendarId = 'cicuser3@gmail.com';
          $event = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);
          printf('Event created: %s\n', $event->htmlLink);
    }
```

[image: Error Image]

Comment: How are you downloading the client library?  Its not installed properly.    Could you include tthe rest of your code please make sure that you have included   require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

Comment: Yes sir I have require_once vendor/autoload.php. But it is still showing me the erorr. Is it possible can i share you screen of my computer so you better see the code and project. It will better to assist

Comment: Since you have copied the example directly from the documentation did you also follow this for installing it using composer?  https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/php

Comment: I have just used the composer to install google/apiclient:^2.0 but don't create a quickstart.php.

Comment: OK I have solved all that issue now facing this error:
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Google_Service_Exception
Message: { "error": { "code": 401, "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.", "errors": [ { "message": "Login Required.", "domain": "global", "reason": "required", "location": "Authorization", "locationType": "header" } ], "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED" }

Comment: Can you post your authorization code how are you creating $service?